# Mobile Redirect with .htaccess and javascript

Tags: redirect, mobile

I have a main website and a mobile website, and to automatically redirect visitors to the mobile website I have used .htaccess redirect and a javascript screen size redirect (as a backup). My question: is it ok to use both of these together? I'm not very familiar with this type of programming so am not sure if they will cancel each other out or conflict in some way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using .htaccess and also using javascript.
But just be careful that it one rule mite override another rule and also note that javascript takes the precedence over .htaccess.

My suggestion would be, if you are redirecting by device name using .htaccess and if you are redirecting by size use javascript.